# Imagemagick transparency not working in 6.9 but works in 7.0

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, crop, imagemagick-convert

I'm running this command to crop an image and retain (alpha?) transparency:

```
convert bigger.png -crop 2048x2048 -gravity northwest \
-extent 2048x2048 -transparent white \ 
-set 'filename:tile' '%[fx:page.x/2048]_%[fx:page.y/2048]' 'tile_%[filename:tile].png'
```

I'm using the exact same command, but on three different versions.

- 6.7.2-7 2017-03-23 Q16 (Linux, not sure which dist)
- 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 (Linux/Ubuntu)
- 7.0.8-42 Q16 x86_64 (Mac Os Mojave)

On 7.0 it works perfectly, but on 6.x, the background is black after conversion.

Is there some option that was changed in 7.0 that I can try in the old versions?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I tried different combination of these parameters and adding PNG32 to force an alpha channel:

`-alpha on -background none -transparent white PNG32:bigger.png`

Comment: It seems like -background none is working, but it needs to be before the -extent command.

Comment: settings need to come before operators that use them. But in this case `-background none` does nothing. `-transparent` will make the image transparent. Perhaps you should show the full command line. PNG32: preface should not be needed in this case, but it does not hurt to add it. 6.7.2.7 and 6.9.7.4 are ancient or known to have problems. Also note that on Linux, they patch without updating the versions most of the time. So the date is more important. Patches are often only for security fixes. Your black issue could be due to different versions of libpng.